# Get text font from an image using GIMP

Tags: fonts, gimp, text, font-identification, images

I have an image which contains a text. I don't know the text font. Is there any way to find the text font from an image using GIMP?

[image]

I need to know what font is used in this text image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have the original Gimp file with the text still as a text layer, no you can't. Identifying a font from a raster image is complex and well beyond the scope of Gimp's feature set.

There are online services that can help with font identification from an image, such as [What The Font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

You can also ask here on GD.SE, but make sure you ask a [good question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), providing the research you've done.

Edit: Check [the font identification question requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions) before asking a font identification question.

Comment: Worth mentioning the [font-id question requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366/52050), which also contains a list of more font id services/tools.

Comment: Thanks--I knew I saw those at one time but couldn't find them just now. I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone reads this incredibly over complicated answer today.. even in 2016 this is how you do this: Use a virtual machine and install W7 to be lightweight about it. Get a trial with Adobe Creative cloud. Highlight the text with the standard rectangle marquee selection tool. Select Select typeset and auto recognize should be easy to find from there. It will even open in creative cloud if you install the actual suite and populate the font for you.

Just wanted to help someone who stumbles across the post in the future.

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing. You do realize that this is a *GIMP* question right? And what's that with a virtual machine? For Linux? I'm guessing you are talking about the *Type > Match Font* function in Photoshop? But you don't mention which application to use, just to "highlight the text".